# How to estimate exponential MLL function + add confidence intervals in R gpplot2?

Tags: r, exponential, log-likelihood, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to plot the raw data along with the exponential curve fit and add confidence intervals for maximum likelihood model function in R. My data is stored in df(x.number, y.size). I'm trying to run MLL using the skewfun in R

I want to use estimates from the model to plot the curve + 95% confidence intervals along with the raw data, but I keep running into errors (`Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) :  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0`)

```
library(stats4)
library(ggplot2)

#Data
y.size <- c(2.69,4.1,8.04,3.1,5.27,5.033333333,3.2,7.25,6.29,4.55,6.1,2.65,3.145,3.775,3.46,5.73,5.31,4.425,3.725,4.32,5,3.09,5.25,5.65,3.48,6.1,10,9.666666667,6.06,5.9,2.665,4.32,3.816666667,3.69,5.8,5,3.72,3.045,4.485,3.642857143,5.5,6.333333333,4.75,6,7.466666667,5.03,5.23,4.85,5.59,5.96,5.33,4.92,4.255555556,6.346666667,4.13,6.33,4,7.35,6.35,4.63,5.13,7.4,4.28,4.233333333,4.3125,6.18,4.3,4.47,4.88,4.5,2.96,2.1,3.7,3.62,5.42,3.8,5.5,3.27,3.36,3.266666667,2.265,3.1,2.51,2.51,4.4,2.64,4.38,4.53,2.29,2.87,3.395,3.26,2.77,3.22,4.31,4.73,4.05,3.48,4.8,4.7,3.05,4.21,5.95,4.39,4.55,4.27,4.955,4.65,3.32,3.48,3.828571429,4.69,4.68,3.76,3.91,4,4.41,4.19,4.733333333,4.32,2.83,3.41,4.42,3.47,3.84,4.39)

x.number <- c(69,62,8,80,13,12,2,22,19,49,840,44,31,56,33,58,91,8,15,86,11,69,12,24,32,27,1,4,26,4,28,33,1516,41,20,58,44,29,58,14,3,3,6,3,26,52,26,29,92,30,18,11,27,19,38,78,57,52,17,45,56,7,37,7,14,13,164,76,82,14,273,122,662,434,126,374,1017,522,374,602,164,5,191,243,134,70,23,130,306,516,414,236,172,164,92,53,50,17,22,27,92,48,30,55,28,296,35,12,350,17,22,53,97,62,92,272,242,170,37,220,452,270,392,314,150,232)
df <- data.frame(x.number, y.size)
df <- df[df$x.number < 750,] #data

#Plotting using stat_smooth function
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x.number,y=y.size))+ geom_point(shape=21, fill="white", color="red", size=3)+ stat_smooth(method="nls",formula =  y~(a*exp(-x*b) + c),method.args=list(start=c(a=10,b=0.05,c=3)),se=F,color="red")+ stat_smooth(method="lm",formula =  y~a*exp(-x*b)+c ,se=F,color="blue") + theme_classic()
```

[image]

```
 #MLL function
a = 10; b = 0.05; c = 3; sigma = 1
expreg <- function(a,b,c, sigma){
  y.pred <- a * exp(-x.number*b) + c
  ll <-   -sum(dnorm(y.size, mean = y.pred, sd = sigma, log=TRUE ))
  # cat(a, b, sigma, ll, "\n")
  ll
}
#Here I keep running into an error that reads
Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) :    Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0

#Computing MLL

mle2.expreg.model <- mle(expreg, start = list(a = 9, b = 0.03, c = 3 , sigma = 1))
summary(mle2.expreg.model)
-logLik(mle2.expreg.model)
AIC(mle2.expreg.model)

#Plot with MLL estimates
a <- 8.66
b <- 12.67
c <- 4.48
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x.number,y=y.size))+ geom_point(shape=21, fill="white", color="red", size=3)+ stat_function(fun=function(x)a*exp(-x*b) + c, color = "blue")  + My_Theme + theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + ylab("Female Size (mm)") + xlab ("Number of Females/ Host")
```